# Finding which .NET assembly defines a type

Tags: c#, .net, msdn

If I recall correctly, in the good old C++ days MSDN used to be helpful in that it would show you not only the header file you needed to include to access a particular function, but also the DLL you needed to link to where that functionality was implemented. But these days, while MSDN tells you the namespace in which an object is defined, it doesn't tell you what reference you need to add to get at that object. Isn't or shouldn't there be a simple way to find all the .NET objects referenced in various answers posted about the web, mostly here on SO? How do you find which assembly contains an object? (I happen to be looking for `System.ComponentModel.ExpandableObjectConverter` at the moment.)

Comment: Msdn shows all Assembly names for .Net core types.

Comment: @MUG4N That's not going to work if you don't know what assembly to include in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The information is visible on [the documentation page for system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter.aspx).

Just below the inheritance hierarchy, near the top of the page, you can see this:

> **Namespace:**  System.ComponentModel
>   **Assembly:**  System (in System.dll)

Comment: Was this only recently added?  I could of sworn that I've had the same problem of not knowing the assembly as the OP in the past.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, it's been there as long as I can remember

Comment: Strange, I was just looking and could not find it, yet the page you link to (and the page where I was looking) shows it! I guess I expected it to be at the bottom, so I've just been looking in the wrong place all this time! I thought I hadn't referenced it because I was trying to use it as an attribute -- I guess I was also misusing the class, which presented another level of difficulties.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN There is simply too much information. I often missed it even though I knew it had to be there ;)